# How to revert cached entity object to last persisted state?

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa

I have a relatively run of the mill `MVC` scenario where the view (`JSF`) loads a list of managed entities in an `EJB` via a `managed bean` using a `NamedQuery` defined in that `Entity` class.  Each entity is modifiable in the view, the collection of which is represented by the `Primefaces` component `p:accordionPanel`.  In each tab of the panel is a form that allows updates to the corresponding entity:

**JSF:**

```
<p:accordionPanel id="entityAccordion" value="#{managedBean.entityList}" 
    var="entity" multiple="false" dynamic="true" cache="true">
```

**Managed bean:**

```
public List<Appeal> getEntityList() {

    //this loads entities from DB
    return manager.getEntityList(this.parentID)
}
```

When the user changes form values in the view, `AJAX` automatically updates the cached entity in the managed bean.  The commision of the new values, however, is triggered only by hitting the submit button in the form.  Between the first form change and the submission, the state of the cached entity object is different from its corresponding DB row.  I need to implement a reversion of the DB state to the form in case the user changes their mind and cancels their changes.  I cannot do it by merely refreshing the view because that will get me the cached object from the managed bean, which, due to AJAX, is identical to what is in the view -- I need to first refresh the cached object to what is last persisted in the DB and then refresh the view with the cached object.

So far, I have tried several things, none of which worked:

**EJB:**

```
//this fails because it reconstructs new entity object 
//but managed bean keeps binding to the old one
public void refreshEntity(Entity entity) {

    //I had to do this prior to refresh as without it says entity is not managed
    //but it reconstructs the instance rather than refresh existing
    Entity result = this.entityManager.find(Entity.class, entity.getID());

    this.entityManager.refresh(result);

    return result;
}

//not sure why this fails but i tried it as per JPA spec
public void clearEntity() {

    this.entityManager.clear();

}
```

As you can see in the comment of the first attempted solution, it doesn't work because the managed bean seems to keep reference to the old object while the EJB refresh method changes the pointer of that variable to a wholly new constructed object.  I was hoping that the managed bean would repoint to the new object after garbage collecting the old one but it doesn't do that, rendering the refresh (at least the way I am doing it) useless.

**How can I revert the cached entity object to its last persisted state while keeping all the view bindings to that object?**

It might be useful to mention that we are using the JPA API in our application, which uses the `Hibernate` implementation in the backend.

Comment: Why can't you just discard the entity in your managed bean and reload that one? Could you add the `manager.getEntityList()` code?

Comment: The answer to that question is in the paragraph just before the bolded question above

Comment: _"while the EJB refresh method changes the pointer of that variable to a wholly new constructed object"_ How did you verify this? _"I was hoping that the managed bean would repoint to the new object after garbage collecting the old one"_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: I verified it by debugging and keeping track of the object ID.  when i refreshed, a new object (with a new object ID) was assigned to the same variable but when i put a breakpoint in the getter that populates the UI component, the object ID of the entity was still pointing to the old object (i know by looking at the ID).  i was hoping it would have been GC-ed

Comment: I still don't see the connection between `manager.getEntityList()` and `refreshEntity`. The `EntityManager` will usually return a new entity object, so I guess you are getting your entity from somewhere else. It would be important to see the content of `manager.getEntityList()`...