# Why is 'Entity not managed' once passed from EJB to managed bean?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, managed-bean

I am dealing with an issue whereby I try to do a `EntityManager.refresh` on a `JPA`/`Hibernate` mapped `Entity` after the entity has been passed to the `managed bean`.  From the managed bean, I call a method `refreshEntity` in the `EJB` but I get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Entity not managed
```

This should not be the case because the entity should in fact be managed as I have just loaded it in the EJB via JPA:

```
public List<Entity> loadEntities(Parent _parent) {

    List<Entity> result = null;

    Query query = this.entMngr.createNamedQuery("Entity.getAllForParent");

    query.setParameter("parent", _parent);

    try {
        result = (List<Entity>)query.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException e) { 

    }

    return result;
}
```

That method is called in the managed bean:

```
private void refreshEntityList() {

    this.entityList = this.mngrBean.loadEntities(this.parent);
}
```

However, as soon as any entity has been passed out of the EJB to the managed bean, it stops being managed and I know it because I created the following method in the EJB:

```
public void refreshEntity(Entity entity) {

    this.entMngr.refresh(entity);
}
```

which fails when being called from the managed bean by throwing the above exception.  In further debugging, I tried invoking `refreshEntity` from `loadEntities` above in a loop (just for testing, no functional value), right before the return:

```
for(Entity item : result) {
    this.refreshAppeal(item);
}
```

which worked.  However, doing the same immediately after in the managed bean's `refreshEntityList` fails giving the error.

**What happens to the entity on its way from the EJB to the managed bean so that it stops being managed?**

Comment: If everything is not happening within the same transaction, then the Entity will become detached. Do any of these methods participate in Transactions?

Comment: i don't have a transaction defined...  but could

Comment: Entities only remain 'attached' to the persistence session while you are in the same transaction that loaded them. Leave the transaction and the session is closed. When the session closes the Entities are detached (no longer managed).

Comment: unfortunately, my problem is that it is impractical to combine the loading of the entities in a transaction because they are loaded all together but they are transacted upon (updated) individually

Comment: Can you call `merge` to add them back to the persistence context when you come to transact on them?

Comment: merge will make the update in the DB

Comment: No, `merge` will just re-attach the Entity to the persistence context. See [this page of the OpenJPA documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_em_lifecycle.html) for a good explanation of the Entity life-cycle.

Comment: i actually use `EntityManager.merge(Object)` to update existing entities in the DB instead of `persist`.  I tried using persist but it didn't work on existing, only new rows.  I'm afraid if I do what you say I will commit any changes from the in-memory entity to the DB, which I don't want

Comment: Then why do you want to `refresh` the entity? If you just want to reload it, then just do another get/find. If the Entity has been changed, refreshing the Entity would overwrite your changes from the values in the database anyway. Perhaps you need to clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve (your goal).

Comment: here is why:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570037/how-to-revert-cached-entity-object-to-last-persisted-state

Comment: If you really want to stick with your solution, you can try to investigate so-called "extended persitence context approach": http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/building_perfect_anti_facades_almost . Just be sure that your EJB is not accessed by a remote interface, as it works with @Local only as far as I remember...

Comment: Belated, is the entity 'injected' into managed bean?